# Deploying chaincode failed (Ubuntu 18.04 fabric-sample)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I'm following the Hyperledger Fabric Doc, `network.sh up` and `network.sh createChannel` is running successfully.

But when I run `./network.sh deployCC` it's giving the below error

> No chaincode name was provided. Valid call example: ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
> Deploying chaincode failed

[image: error]

Comment: Hey and welcome Jeff. Please share the content of `network.sh`. Also share the error message as text not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like no default value is set for the chaincode name. You can specify the chaincode name using the flag `ccn` in `./network.sh deployCC` command. e.g. `./network.sh deployCC  -ccn test_chaincode`.

You might have to provide values for other flags as well like for flag `ccp` which is chaincode path etc. Have a look at the list of all the flags [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#bring-up-the-test-network) or you can just simply run `./network.sh -h` to print the script help text.

Comment: yes. I used command "./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go" , it success. Thank you very much.

and if met " Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: go: github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.2 " issue. Maybe to replace goproxy by "go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct" .

Answer (score 0):

need to provide a chaincode name or set a default chaincode name in deployCC script file.